# When comparing any to void why is the type a union?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I wanted to check if a supplied type was `void` and was surprised to find that when passing in `any` a union is returned. Could someone please explain why this is?

```
type test<T> = T extends void ? void extends T ? 1 : 0 : 0;

type v1 = test<any>; // 1 | 0
type v2 = test<unknown>; // 0
type v3 = test<undefined>; // 0
type v4 = test<null>; // 0
type v5 = test<never>; // never
type v6 = test<void>; // 1
type v7 = test<boolean>; // 0
type v8 = test<string>; // 0
type v9 = test<number>; // 0
type v10 = test<'void'>; // 0
type v11 = test<{}>; // 0
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/C4TwDgpgBMEM7ADwBUB8UC8VlQgD1gDsATOKANwHsBLYqAfgprvyNOwagEYoAuKAAx9BAbgCwAKEmhIFHllgJEAQ0IhU4iTOjkATJhjwkAV0IBrQpQDuhDdPA6AzAcUmSEAGbVCEYna0OFAAsLkaIhMYANpH%202hQArKFKPuQQAE6xgeQAbElIVLSZsuQA7HmIAEaUlJEQqkU6ABzlCGneAOYNFACc5REAthXpXeRcQgphAOQFxJMjXPKGSgDeAL4aQA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [microsoft/TypeScript#40049](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40049) for an authoritative answer.  When `any` is checked via a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), the result will be the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of both the true and false branches.  This may be surprising, but it is working as intended.

Relevant comment:

> This isn't especially well-documented outside of the source-code, but in the checker you'll find in the relevant place:
>
> ```
> // Return union of trueType and falseType for 'any' since it matches anything
> if (checkType.flags & TypeFlags.Any) {
> ```
>
> So `any` is treated like a wildcard that matches both branches.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response, thinking about it now that makes complete sense. As the author of that issue goes on to ask, i also need to get a better understanding of how `extends` actually works under the hood

Comment: I don't know how much sense it makes, personally.  I mean, `any extends X` is true for all `X` except for `never`, so presumably it would take the true branch no matter what.  It is sometimes useful to [distribute](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) the operation across unions in the checked type, but `any` is not a union.

Comment: There are lots of little gotchas with conditional types.  For example, you didn't ask why `v5` is `never` when neither branch is `never`.  That's because `never` is [the "empty union"](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23182#issuecomment-379094672) and so if you have a distributive conditional type, the `never` input becomes `never` output.

Answer (score 1):

I think I managed to understand this:

`void extends any ? 1 : 0` resolves to `1`, meaning void does extend any. I imagine this is a design decision from Typescript authors, I wasn't able to find the reason for this. From my tests - all types extend `any` (checked with `{}, () => 1, "v", 3, unknown`).

Then, `any extends void ? 1 : 0` resolves to `1 | 0` which actually makes sense (it would be one of the two types in the conditional type).

As a result

```
 ==> test<any>
     === any extends void ? void extends any ? 1 : 0 : 0
     === any extends void ? 1 : 0
     === 1 | 0
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/C4TwDgpgBMEM7ADwBUB8UC8VlQgD1gDsATOKANwHsBLYqAfgprvyNOwagEYoAuKAAx9BAbgCwAKEmhIFHllgJEAQ0IhU4iTOjkATJhjwkAV0IBrQpQDuhDdPA6AzAcUmSEAGbVCEYna0OFAAsLkaIhMYANpH%202hQArKFKPuQQAE6xgeQAbElIVLSZsuQA7HmIAEaUlJEQqkU6ABzlCGneAOYNFACc5REAthXpXeRcQgphAOQFxJMjXPKGSgDeAL7%209rIAxgAWEFtmizO4BBAkZKognDz8AiJQAPQP3JvQu-tm%20liXJ2xkx4wbqJHs8eAAfQSSSRPTAYdCuFRqVDQ55QNFojCYqA-VhndgApi0X54i5qa7CIS3FHo9GY75k3HnQl0QEU6k02FYcGCIA)